# Defining a scale factor to graph three quantities, the sum of which is constant

Tags: c++, stdout, stdstring

I am trying to write a graph in standard output, the program returns rows of "#" that should add up to the initial quantity after another function changes them. I guarantee that the function that modifies the numbers is not at fault. This is my code :

```
struct mystruct {
    long long int s;
    long long int i;
    long long int r;
}

mystruct initial_;

void draw_row(mystruct P)
{
    long long int Ntotal = initial_.s + initial_.i;
    int scale = round(Ntotal / 10);
    std::string a(Ntotal / scale, '#');
    std::string b(round(P.s / scale), '#');
    std::string c(round(P.i / scale), '#');
    std::string d(round(P.r / scale), '#');
    std::cout << P.s << " " << P.i << " " << P.r << '\n';
    std::cout << scale << '\n';
    std::cout << a << '\n' << b << c << d << '\n';
}
```

These are examples of some of its outputs :

```
499 1 0
##########
#########

0 450 50
##########
##########

0 249 251
##########
#########
```

Comment: I know because on every iteration the sum of all three parameters are positive integers and their sum is costant (in this case 500). The desired output should be like the second example of outputs, where the first row of "#"  is equal to the second one. The number of "#" in the first row is simply the total over the scale factor,rounded.  Second row is the sum of the the three parameters,individually divided by the scale factor and rounded. In this case the inputs are the numbers above every couple of rows and the outputs are the rows themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing integer divisions in the lines

```
int scale = round(Ntotal/10) ; 
std::string a(Ntotal/scale,'#') ;
std::string b(round(P.s/scale),'#') ;
std::string c(round(P.i/scale),'#') ;
std::string d(round(P.r/scale),'#') ;
```

and the remainders are truncated, so `round()` used here aren't working as expected.

You can do `(A + B/2) / B` to round the division result of two positive integers `A / B`, so the lines should be

```
int scale = (Ntotal+5)/10 ; 
std::string a(Ntotal/scale,'#') ;
std::string b((P.s+scale/2)/scale,'#') ;
std::string c((P.i+scale/2)/scale,'#') ;
std::string d((P.r+scale/2)/scale,'#') ;
```

Comment: I solved my problem thanks to your answer, although I did not use your code. I used `double scale = Ntotal/10` and kept the `round()` functions. Is there any reason that I can not notice that makes your solution better or are they equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

I take the first column drawn shows the max possible value, that is `a = Ntotal = initial_.s + initial_.i >= P = P.s + P.i + P.r`, everything divided by `scale`.

The second `P.s + P.i + P.r` column is sometimes shorter than the first `Ntotal` one because of the truncation error introduced by multiple integer divisions (`scale = round(Ntotal/10)` and `b, c, d = round(P.(s, i, r)/scale)`).

You cannot totally defeat the problem, but you can improve the representation by enlarging the scale, that is by reducing the `scale` parameter, which would stretch the columns longer (they will end up containing more `#`).